# undefined method `all' when rake db:seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, seed

I am trying to seed my database, but I am running into this error, and as a beginner do not know how to fix it.  Here is the error (with rb.33 pointing to  bookmarks = Bookmarks.all):

```
vagrant@rails-dev-box:~/code/bookmarks$ rake db:seed
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `all' for Bookmarks:Module
/home/vagrant/code/bookmarks/db/seeds.rb:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:540:in `load_seed'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.0.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:154:in `load_seed'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.0.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:181:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is my seeds.rb file:

```
require 'faker'

# Create a User
 user = User.new(
   name:     'First Last',
   email:    'firstlast@gmail.com',
   password: 'password',
 )
 user.skip_confirmation!
 user.save

#Create Bookmarks
10.times do
  Bookmark.create!(
    url:    Faker::Internet.url
  )
end
bookmarks = Bookmarks.all

#Create Topics
10.times do
  Topic.create!(
    name:   Faker::Lorem.sentence
  )
end
topics = Topic.all


users.each do |user|
  3.times do
    user.bookmarks << Bookmark.sample
  end
end

topics.each do |topic|
  3.times do
    user.topics << Topic.sample
 end
end

puts "Seed finished"
puts "#{User.count} users created"
puts "#{Bookmark.count} bookmarks created"
puts "#{Topic.count} topics created"
```

And here is my create bookmark code (which I have tested and it works):

```
def create
    bookmark = Bookmark.where(url: params[:bookmark][:url]).first

    @bookmark = bookmark.present? ? bookmark : Bookmark.new(bookmark_params)

    if @bookmark.save
      @bookmark.users << current_user
      Rails.logger.info ">>>>>>>>>>>>> Bookmark: #{@bookmark.inspect}"

      topic_names = params[:topic_names].split(' ')
      topic_names.each do |topic_name|
        name = topic_name.sub(/#/, '')

        @bookmark.topics << Topic.find_or_create_by_name(name)
      end
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @bookmark, notice: 'Bookmark was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @bookmark }
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @bookmark.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end   
  end
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> NoMethodError: undefined method `all' for Bookmarks:Module

*Model names in rails are by convention singular and **since you already have `Bookmark.create` in your seeds so i guess you have a typo. It should be Bookmark.all not Bookmarks.all***

```
bookmarks = Bookmark.all
```

Comment: Good eye, @Mandeep. Now I'm getting NoMethodError: undefined method `sample' for #<Class:0xaa90cf4>.  I'm trying to take a sample of bookmarks and assign them to some of my users.  Any ideas why this is throwing an error?

Comment: @ValerieMettler #sample is a method of an instance of an Array. So it should be *something* like Database.all.sample

Comment: @paulorcdiniz is right. Sample is a method for array class and you are trying to use it as a class method which you haven't define